# Is there any way to protect my json connection password, when i use it in my android app?

Tags: android, json

I have an android app. I'm using json api to fetch data from database. But api credentials are stored in my app. I don't want it. Because there are some ways to show android source codes.

Are there any way fetch data securely but credentials are not stored in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Keystore.The Keystore is not used directly for storing application secrets such as password, however, it provides a secure container, which can be used by apps to store their private keys, in a way that’s pretty difficult for malicious (unauthorised) users and apps to retrieve.

[How to use the Android Keystore to store passwords and other sensitive information](https://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-keystore-store-passwords-sensitive-information-623779/)

[Where is the best place to store a password in your Android app](https://www.androidauthority.com/where-is-the-best-place-to-store-a-password-in-your-android-app-597197/)

Comment: Using keystore is safer but i am not sure that it’s the best way. 
Could we know that the app is installed from google play when it is making requests?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't catch your question. Do you mean after success response you want to check app is installed or not?

Comment: No, i want to know who is the client? (is the application downloaded from google play? or is the client an android app?)